# How to fully live update sphinx indexing?

Tags: automation, indexing, sphinxsearch

It's covered in sphinx documents:

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#live-updates

But after reading it,I don't think it really can achieve that.

Have you guys ever also thought of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the terms *live update indexing* and *almost real-time* are terribly misleading. Perhaps *incrementally updating index* is appropriate for what sphinx is really doing there.

Having said that, for my applications of interest, the biggest limitation of the delta+main solution presented  is that only new data is indexed with the deltas -- previously indexed data which has been updated in the db is not flagged for re-indexing.

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite old now, however, I've come across the similar problem recently.

I use delta and main indices in my application. I use cron to schedule indices' rotations. The delta index is being updated every few minutes and the main index once a day. This updates both indices.

For example:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/indexer delta --rotate --quiet

00 7 * * * /path/to/indexer main --rotate --quiet
```